# Выводит ошибку "Error:(105, 35) Unresolved reference: builderExpression". Как исправить?

Tags: kotlin, build-error

```
tvEquals.setOnClickListener {
                val text = tvExpression.text.toString()
                val expression = builderExpression(text).build()

                val result = expression.evaluate()
                val longResult = result.toLong()
                if (result == longResult.toDouble()) {
                    tvResult.text = longResult.toString()
                } else {
                    tvResult.text = result.toString()
                }
            }
```

Comment: Импортировать тип/функцию `builderExpression` вверху файла.

Comment: @Igor, можете пояснить, пожалуйста? Что следует сделать?

Comment: Добавьте метку языка программирования в вопрос

Comment: @insolor От этого ошибка не исчезнет :). котлин, наверное.

Comment: @Igor, зато на вопрос обратят внимание люди, специализирующиеся на данном языке. `котлин, наверное` - вот чтобы не гадать нужно чтобы автор вопроса добавила метку.